# Why does the Swift Compiler throw an error on inferring the type of my Generic Element when the Element is clearly constrained?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, compiler-errors

As I was working with implementing an Array that keeps weak references to its elements I stumbled on a Compile Error as soon as I used the methods of the `Collection` extension methods, before using the `Collection` method the code compiled correctly and expectedly.

### Expected Behavior

The code should compile with no error.

### Current Behavior

The compiler throws the two following Errors:

1. WeakRef requires that Element? be a class type
2. Could not infer type for 'items'

### Possible Solution

The only solution I found is to make the property items public and use a for-loop instead of the `Collection` extensions methods. After doing this the compiler was able to infer the type for `items` and even the `Collection` methods worked.

### Steps to Reproduce

First implement the `WeakRef` class:

```
final class WeakRef<T: AnyObject> {

    weak var value: T?

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

}
```

Second implement the `WeakArray` struct:

```
struct WeakArray<Element: AnyObject> {

    public var items: [WeakRef<Element>] = []

    init(_ elements: [Element]) {
        items = elements.map { WeakRef($0) }
    }
}
```

Third implement the `Collection` extension implementation:

```
extension WeakArray: Collection {

    var startIndex: Int { return items.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Int { return items.endIndex }

    subscript(_ index: Int) -> Element? {
        return items[index].value
    }

    func index(after idx: Int) -> Int {
        return items.index(after: idx)
    }

}
```

Fourth create an instance of the WeakArray property not in the same source file however as `WeakArray` for example:

```
var objects: WeakArray<UIViewController> = WeakArray.init([])
```

Fifth and final step call a method of the `Collection` protocol for example:

```
objects.forEach({ $0?.view.backgroundColor = .white })
```

### Context (Environment)

This code won't compile on the version of Xcode Version 9.3.1 (9E501) using Swift 4.1

### Additional Description

The solution for the above code was found in the following links:

1. https://marcosantadev.com/swift-arrays-holding-elements-weak-references/
2. https://www.objc.io/blog/2017/12/28/weak-arrays/

Thank you in advance to any help provided. This post was completely edited to fit Stackoverflow standards of asking a question. Special thanks to MartinR for guiding me to post a good question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Collection` has an associated `Element` type, and that seems to
conflict with your generic `Element` placeholder. Using a different
name `E` for the placeholder solves the problem:

```
struct WeakArray<E: AnyObject> {

    public var items: [WeakRef<E>] = []

    init(_ elements: [E]) {
        items = elements.map { WeakRef($0) }
    }
}

extension WeakArray: Collection {

    var startIndex: Int { return items.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Int { return items.endIndex }

    subscript(_ index: Int) -> E? {
        return items[index].value
    }

    func index(after idx: Int) -> Int {
        return items.index(after: idx)
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly thank you very much again! Much appreciated!